# Eclipse messes up my text by converting tabs into spaces

Tags: eclipse, tabs, whitespace, spaces, csv

Opened up a tab separated file in Eclipse. When I copy one line and then paste it into the same file, all the tabs have been converted into spaces. This *kind of* ruins the tab separated format...

How can I stop Eclipse from messing up my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> 
  Insert spaces for tabs
```

Comment: Ah, finally the madness is gone, hehe. Thanks!